# Junit @Tag - can't get the any() and none() tags to work when running tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, tags, junit5

I have a spring boot project with some integration tests.  The tests are tagged with annoations like

```
@Test
@Tag("Slow")
```

Some tests have no tags at all.

I'm interested in using tags to run the tests and also using the any() and none() options when running tests - [more on that here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions).

I have a project using this maven config:

```
<junit-jupiter.verison>5.6.2</junit-jupiter.verison>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-jupiter.verison}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Yet, when I try to run my tests either from the command line or through intelliJ, it's not finding any tests when I use the any() or none() options... it works perfectly if I just type "slow" in though.

For example, running this gives 0 tests run:

[image]

How do I use the any() or none() options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to run the tests through `any()` tag as mentioned by you in the IntelliJ jUnit configurations and it works.

You can find more about IntelliJ support [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea)